# Нужен ли знак препинания перед словом ОЗНАЧАЕТ: "Объяснить нечто означает подвести объекты ..."

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении между словами "нечто" и "означает"?
Если не нужна, то разъясните, пожалуйста, почему.

**Как говорит Кант, объяснить нечто означает подвести объекты опыта под установленные природные законы.**

Разве тут не три грамматические основы (*Кант говорит*, *нечто объяснить*, *объекты подвести*)?

Comment: Нет, здесь не три, а две грамматические основы: 1) Кант говорит,  2) объяснить-подлежащее,  означает подвести-сказуемое

Comment: @Людмила, Вам бы стоило оформить отдельный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае "означает" является связкой при сказуемом, выраженном инфинитивом. **Перед связкой «значит», присоединяющей сказуемое к подлежащему, ставится тире. После связки знак препинания не ставится.**

*В свете идти на любовь — значит идти на верный обман.*
В. Соллогуб. Метель.

*У Шекспира есть выражение: понять — значит простить.*
М. Анчаров. Сода-солнце.

*Идти обратно вдоль реки, чтоб наткнуться на знакомую тропу, которая ведет в сосновый бор, — значит потерять день.*
В. Тендряков. Находка.

См.:[**Справочник по пунктуации. Грамота.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)

Comment: Что-то Вы, Серж, намудрили.Значит-связка, а означает - вспомогательный глагол в составном именном сказуемом. Объяснить - подлежащее, означает подвести - составное именное сказуемое, никаких знаков препинания между ними нет. было бы тире, если б было так: ...объяснить нечто - подвести объекты, тире между подлежащим и сказуемым , выраженными инфинитивом.

Comment: Или: ...объяснить нечто - значит подвести объекты...

Comment: Ответ справочной службы: Вопрос № 295105  
Здравствуйте. Нужна ли запятая в предложении между словом "нечто" и "означает"? Если не нужна, то почему? "Как говорит Кант, объяснить нечто означает подвести объекты опыта под установленные природные законы" Разве тут не три грамматические основы? (-Кант говорит-, -нечто объяснить-, -объекты подвести-)
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
Во второй части сложного предложения объяснить — подлежащее, означает подвести — сказуемое. Запятая между ними не ставится.

Comment: @Людмила - двойной агент?  :)

Comment: @Людмила  Инфинитив в качестве присвязочной части составного именного сказуемого употребляется только со связками быть, ***значит, означать***. При этом он нередко параллелен инфинитиву подлежащему.

Comment: Например: Курить – здоровью вредить. Позицию подлежащего при этом занимают, как правило, существительные в именительном падеже с абстрактной семантикой обязан­ность, дело, работа, задача, идея, долг, субстантивированные прилагатель­ные и сочетания самое главное, самое важное и т.п. Инфинитив может иметь любое лексическое значение. Например: Задача – собрать урожай; Наша цель – провестиэксперимент; Самое важное – лечиться.

Comment: https://studopedia.su/3_37662_sostavnoe-imennoe-neglagolnoe-skazuemoe.html

Comment: Серж, я просто выразилась не так. Я не против названия "присвязочный глагол", я против тире.:тире ставится вместо нулевой связки есть, быть, а здесь не нулевая связка, а глагол означает, тире нет.

Comment: Вы же пишете, что перед связкой ставится тире, а после неё не ставится, а вообще-то оно ставится вместо связки, а здесь материально выраженный глагол означает, поэтому тире нет

Comment: Людмила, но ведь перед "значит" тире ставится. Почему здесь не поставить?

Comment: Людмила, я цитировал справочник Грамоты.ру. Тоже сказано и Розенталя.

Comment: Тире ставится перед это, это есть, это значит, вот, если сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже или неопределенной формой, присоединяется посредством этих слов к подлежащему,здесь значит - употребляется в значении связки"это есть", а если значит - глагол 3 лица значить - "имеет смысл, выражает что-то, означает", то тире перед ним не ставится

Comment: Но если это именное сказуемое, тогда придется считать "означает" в данном случае связкой.